# Really basic stuff! use for loop or while function to design a plan that choose minimum number of gifts

Tags: loops, for-loop

there are four gifts, which cost 100, 30, 5, 2. You have $89 to spend on them. now you want to spend as much your money as possible to buy minimum number of gifts (I know it doesn't sound reasonable at first). For example, in this case, starting from the most expensive one, you cannot afford it and thus you can only choose two $30 gifts. Now you have $29 left and you can do 5 $5 gifts and then 2 $2 gifts, totalling 9 gifts with $0 left. This is the plan. The desired output is 9. I need a set of codes that can generate this kind of plan no matter what is inputted at first. If i change the number to 40, 30, 8, 3 and $100, the best plan can still be outputted. 
I got hints that we can input the number from big to small. For example, list1=[100,30,5,2,89] (the cost of gifts first and then the total money you have). And then select maximum amount of the most expensive gifts and see if there's any amount left for other gifts.
it is a beginner question so don't make it look too hard. Just use for loops and while loops (like you just started to learn).
no need to generate random numbers, you can use 100, 30, 5, 2 or other numbers you like.
Thx so much guys I need ur help!!!! kinda desperate now.

Comment: please give put your attempt as code in the question even though it might not even solve the problem.

Comment: sorry i was going to but my attempt does not make any sense. All I know is that for loops and while loops can be used. I started with list1 = [100,30,5,2,89]